# Loading a react dom

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react. I'm looking to build a chrome extension which manipulates a website written in react. When I use the react developer tools (the chrome extension) I can see the full react dom. But I don't know how to load the react dom in my own code.

So, for a minimum working example. If I go to facebook.com (uses react) and load the react dev tools, I see a bunch of FluxContainer tags which have interesting props (e.g. contextArgs, feebacktarget, etc). But from within the javascript console, I don't know how to (a) get access to this react dom and (b) inspect the props of the tags/components of interest.

Answer (score 2):

The dev tools [register a global hook](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/blob/master/backend/backend.js) called `__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__`.

React itself looks to see whether this is present, and if so, calls it from [ReactDOM](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/dom/ReactDOM.js) among other places.

Comment: Interesting - so the solution then would be to spoof the dev tools by setting the __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ variable and implement .inject() on it to capture the react dom?

Comment: @Christopher yes, exactly

Comment: @Christopher in fact, look to see whether it's already set and if so, replace it with a function that first calls the existing function hook, then your stuff. That means the dev tools will keep working

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I really understand your problem but if you want to access to a DOM element of react you can use **ReactDom.findDOMNode(this.refs.REFNAME).optionYouWanted**

example:

```
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

<Radio name='test' ref='First'>5</Radio>
```

If I want to manipulate this radio and get the text for example I will do

```
ReactDom.findDOMNode(this.refs.First).textContent (will return 5);
```

You need to give a ref attribute to the element you want to get

Comment: [String `ref`s are a legacy api](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs) and should now be written as callback functions, e.g. `<Radio name='test' ref={(radio) => { this.radio = radio; }}>5</Radio>`

Comment: The DOM node that I have doesn't have a ref attribute associated with it. So, I have a pre-existing page that is loaded, and I'm trying to get access to the react components.